# Why do I get different answers for this inequality depending on my approach?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm a first year university student, having trouble understanding a basic inequality. Sorry for the formatting, first time posting on this forum. Thanks so much for any help.

$$\frac{2x+5}{x+2}>1$$

If I solve by multiplying both sides by $x+2$, I get:
$$2x + 5 > x+2$$
Subtracting $(x+5)$ from both sides, I get:
$$x > -3$$

However, the other approach I take is subtracting 1 from the original inequality:
$$\frac{2x+5}{x+2}-1>0$$
Then I rewrite the $-1$ as $\frac{-(x+2)}{x+2}$, giving me
$$\frac{2x+5-x-2}{x+2}>0$$
$$=\frac{x+3}{x+2}>0$$
Therefore, we get: $x < -3$ or $x > -2$

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: In first approach, when you multiply by $x+2$ why do you leave the sign of inequality unchanged? Do you know $x+2$ is positive? If you don't know sign of $x+2$ you should consider two cases $x+2>0$ and $x+2<0$ and you know $x+2\neq 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $$\frac{2x+5}{x+2}>1$$

> If I solve by multiplying both sides by $x+2$ I get:
> $$2x + 5 > x+2$$

Here, if you multiply $x+2$ on both sides, you need to make sure $x+2>0$, which means $x>-2$. Otherwise, if $x<-2$, (for example, $x=-3$) but you still do this, the inequality sign will flip. (because $x+2=-3+2=-1$, and you multiply $-1$ on both sides.)